# C++ infinite EOF while loop, searched archive and didn't find similar

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop, eof

This is for a lab in my CS programming class. This is what I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int grade, avg, count = 0, total = 0;

    ifstream gradeFile;
    gradeFile.open("Lab9C.txt");

    gradeFile >> grade;

    while (!gradeFile.eof())
    {
        cout << "Grades: ";

        while (grade != 0)
        {
            cout << grade << " "; 
            count++;
            total = total + grade;
            avg = total / count;
            gradeFile >> grade;
        }

        cout << "Average: " << avg << endl;
    }

    gradeFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

The program is supposed to read each line of a file and print all the grades from that file, then average the grades and print that. Right now It's only printing: Grades: Average: 87 - on infinite repeat. I've tried moving my input statement to different areas, like within the first look and within the second one (initializing grade outside the loop with a grade = -1), and I get infinite loops no matter where I put that statement.

I looked at the other EOF questions on stackoverflow and they all appeared to be different questions. I'm pretty sure I formatted my eof correctly, since it's formatted exactly like the other eof while loops I wrote for this class. So why is it infinitely repeating?

Edit: Both an EOF and a nested sentinel loop are required for this assignment. Instructions:

> • Use an eof controlled while loop to read an unknown number of lines
> from the text file, Lab9C.txt   • Each line will contain quiz grades;
> the last number on each line will be a 0.  This signals the end of
> that set of quiz grades. •    Use a nested while loop (sentinel
> controlled) to read the quiz grades from the file, stopping when it
> reads the 0. •    Print each grade as you read it and print all the quiz
> grades in a set on the same line with spaces in between them. (Don’t
> print the 0.) •   Calculate the average of the quiz grades on a line and
> print it on a separate line with a label. (Use double variables for
> this program.)

Additionally, if it helps, here is the text from the outside file, 0 is intended as an "end line" instruction:

> 80 95 93 87 80 92 0 75 80 85 94 70 0  80 70 90 75 0 79 86 90 95 84 78
> 88 0 65 80 78 90 92 100 0

Ok, Friend turned me on to the solution, I should have put `gradeFile >> grade;` inside the first loop. I'm really annoyed because I was almost certain I had tried that already. Sigh. Either way, it works perfectly now.

Kind of annoyed by the guy who linked the completely inapplicable EOF archived post, which I had read before posting here, and which I already knew didn't apply. I guess some people just post that by habit.

Comment: By the way, shouldn't `count` and `total` be initialized before each inner loop?

Comment: [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Answer (score 0):

EOF is not checked in the loop:

```
        while (grade != 0)
        {
            cout << grade << " "; 
            count++;
            total = total + grade;
            avg = total / count;
            gradeFile >> grade;
        }
```

Therefore, it will run into infinite loop when it reaches EOF without 0 is entered.

On the other hand, when `0` is inputted, no more input will read from the file and therefore no EOF check will performed. This is why `Grades: Average: 87` is repeated endlessly.

To improve:

- Check for EOF in the inner loop.
- Exit from outer loop when no input is taken in inner loop.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int grade, avg, count = 0, total = 0;

    ifstream gradeFile;
    gradeFile.open("Lab9C.txt");

    for(;;)
    {
        cout << "Grades: ";

        bool inputTaken = false;
        while (gradeFile >> grade) // check for EOF in the inner loop
        {
            inputTaken = true;
            if (grade == 0) break;
            cout << grade << " "; 
            count++;
            total = total + grade;
            avg = total / count;
        }
        if (!inputTaken) break; // exit from outer loop when no input is taken in inner loop

        cout << "Average: " << avg << endl;
    }

    gradeFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Why `while(!feof(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: @Barmar Thinking for how to fix...

Comment: @commandershepard Additional information like this should be in your question, not in comments.

Comment: @Barmar - I didn't include while (!feof(file)), because I have nothing in (file).  If you're telling me that (!feof()) is wrong, then why was I taught to use that in class, and what is the alternative for an eof loop?

Comment: @MikeCAT understood, I deleted the comment and edited my original question.

Comment: @MikeCAT RE: initialization, as we were taught it, variables only need to be initialized once in the program to be used throughout.